# sortable - get drop item pointer

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-sortable

I'm using jQuery sortable for drag and drop.

When I click on some element, I can use jQuery "$(this)" in order to get the specific element pointer.

Is there any way to get the same thing after I drop item in some drop-zone? Is there a "$(this)" that will point on the item I just dropped?

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    $( ".dropZone" ).sortable({
        revert: true,
        update: function(event, ui) {

            var dropZoneID = event.target.id;
            var drag_item_ID = ui.item.data('id');
            var pos = (ui.item.index())+1;
            var data = $(this).sortable('serialize', {
              attribute: "data-id"
            });
    });
});
```

HTML - drag item:

```
<div class="panel panel-info attrac-clone" data-id="attrac-2" data-pos="">

    <div class="panel-heading">
        HEADER TITLE
    </div>

    <div class="panel-body">PANEL BODY TEXT</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `item` property of the passed `ui` argument is a reference to the element you just sorted. As such you can use `$(ui.item).closest('.dropZone')`, like this:

```js
$(".dropZone").sortable({
  revert: true,
  update: function(e, ui) {
    var dropZoneID = e.target.id;
    var drag_item_ID = ui.item.data('id');
    var pos = ui.item.index() + 1;
    var data = $(ui.item).closest('.dropZone').sortable('serialize', {
      attribute: "data-id"
    });
  }
});
```